# avoid duplicate code in coffeescript by named function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am trying to declare a function in coffeescript that gets called both upon document ready and when the user types something into a search bar.  Basically, sometimes the searchbar gets rendered with a value, sometimes the user types the value.  I want to display an "x" icon to clear the search bar only if there is text.  The only way I could figure out how to make this work was to write the same code twice, once in the keypress handler, and once on document ready:

```
$ -> 
    $('.clear-search').click ->
        $(this).prev('input').val('').focus();
        $('span.clear-search').hide()

    $('#query_raw_query').keypress ->
        if $('#query_raw_query').length > 0
            $('span.clear-search').show()
        else
            $('span.clear-search').hide()
        end

    if $('#query_raw_query').length > 0
        $('span.clear-search').show()
    else
        $('span.clear-search').hide()
    end
```

What I'd really like to do is just create a function called check_empty or something, and just call it both places, but I can't seem to make it work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ -> 
    someFunctionName = ->
        if $('#query_raw_query').length > 0
            $('span.clear-search').show()
        else
            $('span.clear-search').hide()
        end

    $('.clear-search').click ->
        $(this).prev('input').val('').focus();
        $('span.clear-search').hide()

    $('#query_raw_query').keypress ->
        someFunctionName()

    someFunctionName()
```